# Controlling padding in R plots

Tags: r, plot

### Background

We (my colleagues and I) are using a simple 2-D dataset in order to illustrate the diversity in the current state of affairs in the world of graphing. The idea is to achieve consistent results using a variety of programming languages and plotting applications.

The result is **not** required to be identical. Term "consistent" in this context is related to physical sizes such as dimension (10x10cm) and font as well as colours and line-types.

Now follows two examples:

- GNU plot

[image]

- R

[image]

### Question

1. There is **a lot** of padding in the R plot compared with the GNU version (click the images to see the box), especially at the top of the figure, how can I control it?
2. Are the settings in the `plot` command global? Specifically, when I set `pt=11` (font size 11pt) in the `plot` command does that apply to **all** labels in the plot? The reason I ask is that it sure does not look like the axis labels are 11pt compared with the GNU plot...

**Note:** Fancy answers based on `ggplot` and the like is considered cheating. I want R to handle this natively.

### Example

The example below is the file which produced the R plot above. Note that the output is postscript, the version displayed in the question is a "bitmapped" version.

```
## ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Purpose     : Import comma separated text file to R for plotting
##               x, y1, y2, ....
## Author      : ...
## Contact     : ... (THW)
## Organization: ...
## License     : ...
## Since       : 2016-12-31
## Note        : Two hours of work
## Usage:        $ R ---slave --file=myfig.r
##             : $ ps2pdf -dEPSCrop myfig.ps
## ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Read data
#data = read.csv("../TXT/table.txt", header=FALSE, comment.char="%")

data = data.frame(
  V     = c(0.9261187,0.8576959,0.7943282,0.7356423,0.6812921,0.6309573,
            0.5843414,0.5411695,0.5011872,0.4641589,0.4298662,0.3981072,
            0.3686945,0.3414549,0.3162278,0.2928645,0.2712273,0.2511886,
            0.2326305,0.2154435,0.1995262,0.1847850,0.1711328,0.1584893,
            0.1467799,0.1359356,0.1258925,0.1165914,0.1079775,0.1000000),
  P_T100= c(8977.812 ,9694.019 ,10467.361,11302.396,12204.046,13177.626,
            14228.873,15363.984,16589.648,17913.090,19342.110,20885.130,
            22551.245,24350.274,26292.821,28390.335,30655.178,33100.700,
            35741.314,38592.583,41671.313,44995.649,48585.184,52461.075,
            56646.165,61165.122,66044.580,71313.297,77002.327,83145.200),
  P_T300= c(26933.44 ,29082.06 ,31402.08 ,33907.19 ,36612.14 ,39532.88,
            42686.62 ,46091.95 ,49768.95 ,53739.27 ,58026.33 ,62655.39,
            67653.73 ,73050.82 ,78878.46 ,85171.00 ,91965.54 ,99302.10,
            107223.94,115777.75,125013.94,134986.95,145755.55,157383.22,
            169938.50,183495.37,198133.74,213939.89,231006.98,249435.60),
  P_T500= c(44889.06 ,48470.09 ,52336.80, 56511.98, 61020.23, 65888.13,
            71144.37 ,76819.92 ,82948.24, 89565.45, 96710.55,104425.65,
            112756.22,121751.37,131464.10,141951.67,153275.89,165503.50,
            178706.57,192962.92,208356.56,224978.24,242925.92,262305.37,
            283230.83,305825.61,330222.90,356566.49,385011.63,415726.00))


# Set plotting environment
setEPS()                                      # Somehow fixes the '.eps' output
postscript("myfig.ps", width = 100.0/25.4, height = 100.0/25.4)

# Meticulously set up a new plot
x_range <- c(0, 1)
y_range <- c(0, 500000) 


# Generate a blank plot canvas
plot( range(x_range), range(y_range), type="n", axes=FALSE, frame=FALSE, ps=11,
      xlim=x_range, ylim=y_range, xlab="Volume [m^3]", ylab="Pressure [Pa]")

# Axes
axis(1, at=c(0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0) )
axis(2, at=c(0,1,2,3,4,5)*100000 , las=1, labels=c(0,1,2,3,4,5))
text(0.05 ,500000, expression("x10"^5), cex = 0.8)

# Turn on grid
grid(nx=5, ny=5, col = "lightgray", lty = "dotted")

# Plot
colors = c("blue", "red", "green")
for (i in 1:length(colors) ) {
  lines(data[,1], data[,i+1], type="o", col=colors[i], pch=0, lty=1, cex=.6)
}

labels = c("T=100K", "T=300K", "T=500K")
legend(0.4, 400000, labels, bty = "n", pch=c(0,0,0),
       lty=c(1,1,1), lwd=1, col=colors)

dev.off()
```

Comment: Just a note - as a package-driven language, the vast majority of plotting in R is done with packages like `plot_ly` and `ggplot2`. Excluding them may lead your group to biased findings. Regarding `ps` also note that the documentation says "What is meant by ‘point size’ is device-specific"

Comment: You can find out about the plotting parameters by looking at the help page `?par`.    For this issue,  there are two parameters that you should look at   mai and mar.

Answer (score 1):

@G5W: You put me on the right track here, so thank you for that! [This blog](https://www.r-bloggers.com/setting-graph-margins-in-r-using-the-par-function-and-lots-of-cow-milk/) provides a decent overview of the basics in controlling the margins of an R-plot.

When I take my original plot and print the "lines" in the margin I get the following result:

[image]

which represents the default settings from R. The code stub producing the line numbers is marked with `## -----------------`.

```
data = data.frame(
  V     = c(0.9261187,0.8576959,0.7943282,0.7356423,0.6812921,0.6309573,
            0.5843414,0.5411695,0.5011872,0.4641589,0.4298662,0.3981072,
            0.3686945,0.3414549,0.3162278,0.2928645,0.2712273,0.2511886,
            0.2326305,0.2154435,0.1995262,0.1847850,0.1711328,0.1584893,
            0.1467799,0.1359356,0.1258925,0.1165914,0.1079775,0.1000000),
  P_T100= c(8977.812 ,9694.019 ,10467.361,11302.396,12204.046,13177.626,
            14228.873,15363.984,16589.648,17913.090,19342.110,20885.130,
            22551.245,24350.274,26292.821,28390.335,30655.178,33100.700,
            35741.314,38592.583,41671.313,44995.649,48585.184,52461.075,
            56646.165,61165.122,66044.580,71313.297,77002.327,83145.200),
  P_T300= c(26933.44 ,29082.06 ,31402.08 ,33907.19 ,36612.14 ,39532.88,
            42686.62 ,46091.95 ,49768.95 ,53739.27 ,58026.33 ,62655.39,
            67653.73 ,73050.82 ,78878.46 ,85171.00 ,91965.54 ,99302.10,
            107223.94,115777.75,125013.94,134986.95,145755.55,157383.22,
            169938.50,183495.37,198133.74,213939.89,231006.98,249435.60),
  P_T500= c(44889.06 ,48470.09 ,52336.80, 56511.98, 61020.23, 65888.13,
            71144.37 ,76819.92 ,82948.24, 89565.45, 96710.55,104425.65,
            112756.22,121751.37,131464.10,141951.67,153275.89,165503.50,
            178706.57,192962.92,208356.56,224978.24,242925.92,262305.37,
            283230.83,305825.61,330222.90,356566.49,385011.63,415726.00))


#  ================== P L O T -- P A R A M E T E R S ======================== %

xr = (0.35+1.0)/(0.35+1.0+0.1);
xl =  0.35     /(0.35+1.0+0.1);
yb =  0.80     /(0.80+5.0+0.4);
yt = (0.80+5.0)/(0.80+5.0+0.4);


x_range <- c(0, 1)
y_range <- c(0, 500000) 

x_tics <- c(0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0)
y_tics <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5)


colors = c("blue", "green", "red")
labels = c("T=100K", "T=300K", "T=500K")

#  ============================ P L O T -- 1 ================================ %

# Set plotting environment
setEPS()                                      # Somehow fixes the '.eps' output
postscript("myfig.ps", width = 100.0/25.4, height = 100.0/25.4)

# Meticulously set up a new plot
x_range <- c(0, 1)
y_range <- c(0, 500000) 

# Generate a blank plot canvas
plot( range(x_range), range(y_range), type="n", axes=FALSE, frame=TRUE, ps=11,
      xlab="Volume [m^3]", ylab="Pressure [Pa]")

# Axes
axis(1, at=x_tics )
axis(2, at=y_tics*100000 , las=1, labels=y_tics)
text(0.05 ,500000, expression("x10"^5))

# Turn on grid
grid(nx=5, ny=5, col = "gray", lty = "dotted")

# Plot
for (i in 1:length(colors) ) {
  lines(data[,1], data[,i+1], type="o", col=colors[i], pch=0, lty=1, cex=.6)
}

legend(0.4, 400000, labels, bty = "n", pch=c(0,0,0),
       lty=c(1,1,1), lwd=1, col=colors)

## ----------------------------------------------------- Plot "lines" in margin 
for(j in 1:4) {
  for(i in 0:10) {
     mtext(as.character(i),side=j,line=i)
  }
}

dev.off()
```

The conclusion is that we have too many lines in the margin and need to adjust the function `par` to adjust the parameter `mar`, i.e. the number of lines in the margin, to remove the padding (This was suggested in the comment to my original question). The result when doing this is shown below:

[image]

The code stub is well marked at the end of `## ------ mar` in the example at the end.

However, I am still not pleased and want to move the labels, which are now on line 3 to line 2. This is done using the function `mtext` in the script at the end. The result is shown below:

[image]

Finally, in order to make fine adjustments to the width of the margin I use the `par` function with the variable "mai". The final result is:

[image]

The code stub contains the three changes producing the final plot, they are all marked using the pattern: `## ----------------------`

```
data = data.frame(
  V     = c(0.9261187,0.8576959,0.7943282,0.7356423,0.6812921,0.6309573,
            0.5843414,0.5411695,0.5011872,0.4641589,0.4298662,0.3981072,
            0.3686945,0.3414549,0.3162278,0.2928645,0.2712273,0.2511886,
            0.2326305,0.2154435,0.1995262,0.1847850,0.1711328,0.1584893,
            0.1467799,0.1359356,0.1258925,0.1165914,0.1079775,0.1000000),
  P_T100= c(8977.812 ,9694.019 ,10467.361,11302.396,12204.046,13177.626,
            14228.873,15363.984,16589.648,17913.090,19342.110,20885.130,
            22551.245,24350.274,26292.821,28390.335,30655.178,33100.700,
            35741.314,38592.583,41671.313,44995.649,48585.184,52461.075,
            56646.165,61165.122,66044.580,71313.297,77002.327,83145.200),
  P_T300= c(26933.44 ,29082.06 ,31402.08 ,33907.19 ,36612.14 ,39532.88,
            42686.62 ,46091.95 ,49768.95 ,53739.27 ,58026.33 ,62655.39,
            67653.73 ,73050.82 ,78878.46 ,85171.00 ,91965.54 ,99302.10,
            107223.94,115777.75,125013.94,134986.95,145755.55,157383.22,
            169938.50,183495.37,198133.74,213939.89,231006.98,249435.60),
  P_T500= c(44889.06 ,48470.09 ,52336.80, 56511.98, 61020.23, 65888.13,
            71144.37 ,76819.92 ,82948.24, 89565.45, 96710.55,104425.65,
            112756.22,121751.37,131464.10,141951.67,153275.89,165503.50,
            178706.57,192962.92,208356.56,224978.24,242925.92,262305.37,
            283230.83,305825.61,330222.90,356566.49,385011.63,415726.00))


#  ================== P L O T -- P A R A M E T E R S ======================== %

xr = (0.35+1.0)/(0.35+1.0+0.1);
xl =  0.35     /(0.35+1.0+0.1);
yb =  0.80     /(0.80+5.0+0.4);
yt = (0.80+5.0)/(0.80+5.0+0.4);


x_range <- c(0, 1)
y_range <- c(0, 500000) 

x_tics <- c(0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0)
y_tics <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5)


colors = c("blue", "green", "red")
labels = c("T=100K", "T=300K", "T=500K")

#  ============================ P L O T -- 4 ================================ %
# Set plotting environment
setEPS()                                      # Somehow fixes the '.eps' output
postscript("answer_04.ps", width = 100.0/25.4, height = 100.0/25.4)

## --------------------------------------------------------------- Adjust 'mar' 
#     ‘mar’ A numerical vector of the form ‘c(bottom, left, top, right)’
#          which gives the number of lines of margin to be specified on
#          the four sides of the plot.  The default is ‘c(5, 4, 4, 2) +
#          0.1’.
par(mar=c(3, 3, 1, 0))#
## --------------------------------------------------------------- Adjust 'mai' 
#     ‘mai’ A numerical vector of the form ‘c(bottom, left, top, right)’
#          which gives the margin size specified in inches.
par(mai = c(0.6,0.6,0.22,0.01))

# Generate empty canvas
plot.new()
plot.window(x_range, y_range)

# Axes
axis(side=1, at=c(0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0))
axis(side=2, at=c(0,1,2,3,4,5)*100000 , las=1, labels=c(0,1,2,3,4,5))
mtext(side=3, line=0, expression("x10"^5), adj=0)
## ------------------------------------------------------ Move labels to line 2
mtext(side=1, line=2, "Volume [m^3]")
mtext(side=2, line=2, "Pressure [Pa]")

# Turn on grid
grid(nx=5, ny=5, col = "gray", lty = "dotted")

# Plot
for (i in 1:length(colors) ) {
  lines(data[,1], data[,i+1], type="o", col=colors[i], pch=0, lty=1, cex=.6)
}

legend(0.4, 400000, labels, bty = "n", pch=c(0,0,0),
       lty=c(1,1,1), lwd=1, col=colors)

dev.off()
```